# Is the order of InstanceTypes respected with requesting Spot instances in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My `env.yaml` has:

```
  aws:autoscaling:asg:
    MinSize: "0"
    MaxSize: "1"
  aws:elb:loadbalancer:
    CrossZone: true
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
    ServiceRole: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
    LoadBalancerType: classic
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system:
    SystemType: enhanced
  aws:ec2:instances:
    InstanceTypes: g4dn.xlarge,p2.xlarge,g4dn.2xlarge,g3s.xlarge,t3.xlarge
    EnableSpot: true
    SpotMaxPrice: "0.2"
    SpotFleetOnDemandBase: "0"
    SpotFleetOnDemandAboveBasePercentage: "0"
```

But I'm noticing that it always picks `t3.xlarge` instances. Is that because that's the only affordable one given my price?

Does order matter in `IntanceTypes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does order matter in IntanceTypes?

The order is only important with the On-Demand instances (from EB console):

> Add acceptable instance types for your fleet. **Change their order** to set the launch priority of On-Demand Instances. This **order doesn't affect Spot Instances**. We recommend a minimum of two instance types.

[image]

> Is that because that's the only affordable one given my price?

Also from the EB console:

> Choose a mix of On-Demand and Spot Instances with multiple instance types. Spot Instances are automatically launched at the **lowest available price**.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh. So what I want is the opposite behavior. I want to specify a bunch of instance types that I’d be okay with and set an order. I assume this isn’t possible?

Comment: @Shamoon Hi. For spot only fleet, the order does not matter. Cheapest available will be used. If you were to use regular EC2, not EB, then you would have a bit more control on allocation strategies for spot instances.